# Populate morris.js with php + mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Oh Hello! I can't create charts with mysql using morris.js...
I have a table in my db which is divided into:

```
+----+-------+-----------+---------+
| id | name  | connected | blocked |
+----+-------+-----------+---------+
```

where in connected and blocked is stored respectively **true or false** and **true or false**.

Example:

```
+----+-------+-----------+---------+
| id | name  | connected | blocked |
+----+-------+-----------+---------+
|  1 | cesar | true      | false   |
+----+-------+-----------+---------+
```

And I want to show the number of connected clients, disconnected clients, blocked and unblocked clients in morris.js charts.

I also think my query is wrong... There it is:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "mysql", "charts");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from data");

$array = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) 
{
 array_push(
    $array,
    array(
         'x' => $row['blocked'],
         'y' => $row['connected']
    )
 );
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    'async': true,
    'global': false,
    'url': 'cobaJson.php',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        new Morris.Line({
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            data: json,
            xkey: 'x',
            ykeys: ['y'],
            labels: ['Value']
        });   
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the table name? is it data? if so, "data" is a reserved word. You should use backticks around the table name.

Comment: It's a example...

Comment: It is an example simplifying what I tried to do but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your response, you should see it in the network tab of chrome dev tools.

If it correct chrome can show you your structured data

[image]

If it is not correct you can better manage your query like this:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "mysql", "charts");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from data");
if(!$query) {
  die('Mysql error:'. mysqli_error($link));
}
```

and if there's an error in your query you should see the error in chrome dev tools when the call is performed.

Comment: [{"x":false,"y":true},{"x":true,"y":false},{"x":false,"y":false}]

Comment: I can not create / view the data the way I wrote up there. "And I want to show the number of connected clients, disconnected clients, blocked and unblocked clients in morris.js charts."

Comment: You have to change the code inside the while.

You have to sum your data based on a timeline. It's up to you to decide what minimum interval to use.

Look at this example: http://jsbin.com/uqawig/441/embed?js,output

For you y will be your date_connection, a will be blocked and b will be connected.

Comment: This is not an answer.